# Running SSL node.js server with godaddy gd_bundle.crt

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, x509

I am having trouble getting my SSL server working with the certificate's from godaddy

Using Express: 3.1.0

**Below this works with a key/crt that was generated locally / not signed by go daddy (The browser complains but if you add exception it works.**

```
var http = require('https');    
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/dev/ssl/server.key').toString();
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/dev/ssl/server.crt').toString();
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
    var https = http.createServer(credentials, app);
```

**With godaddy I am provided an extra file gd_bundle.crt which I believe you implement like this, however I am getting an error**

```
var http = require('https');
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/prod/ssl/mysite.key').toString();
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/prod/ssl/mysite.com.crt').toString();
    var ca = fs.readFileSync('/var/www/prod/ssl/gd_bundle.crt').toString();
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca};
    var https = http.createServer(credentials, app);
```

With this configuration I get: Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

Truth be told I am not creating they keys/certs our devops guy does... I am not sure how I can troubleshoot if I am implementing the godaddy ones incorrectly or if there is a way to ensure he setup the key/crt files correctly....

Does anyone see anything blatantly obviously wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Node requires each certificate in the CA chain to be passed separately in an array.  `gd_bundle.crt` probably looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3jCCA...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADCCA...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Each certificate needs to be put in its own file (ie `gd1.crt` and `gd2.crt`) and read separately.

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('mysite.key'),
    certificate: fs.readFileSync('mysite.crt'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('gd1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('gd2.crt')]
});
```

Comment: Yes inside that gd_bundle.crt there is what appears to be two CA's i thought that was odd.... so you are saying i need to edit it and put them in two files and load them in the array. I will try this thank you!

Comment: Confirming putting each `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` ... `END CERTIFICATE` block in a separate file, then using an array as shown here, worked for me. Solved site that seemed fine on desktop but was not trusted on android, using concatenated "apache bundle file" from comodo.

Comment: I tried the same, but I am getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error. I received 2 files, `1a67ca890634629a.crt` & `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. What should I do now ?

Comment: In case more people saw this, `gd_bundle-g2-g1.cr` is likely the one that needs to be edited and split into multiple files that passsed to `ca` param. `1a67ca890634629a.crt` should only contain one block that is likely to be your certificate, i.e. goes into `certificate` param.

Answer (score 11):

Ask GoDaddy for your ssl certificate in **SHA-1 signature** and break the bundle file into two files, this way...

FROM your `gd_bundle.crt`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3jCCA8agAwIBAgICAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwYzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
RE4+uXR21aITVSzGh6O1mawGhId/dQb8vxRMDsxuxN89txJx9OjxUUAiKEngHUuH
qDTMBqLdElrRhjZkAzVvb3du6/KFUJheqwNTrZEjYx8WnM25sgVjOuH0aBsXBTWV
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
56yDqg+2DzZduCLzrTia2cyvk0/ZM/iZx4mERdEr/VxqHD3VILs9RaRegAhJhldX
RQLIQTO7ErBBDpqWeCtWVYpoNz4iCxTIM5CufReYNnyicsbkqWletNw+vHX/bvZ8
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

TO `gd_bundle_01.crt`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3jCCA8agAwIBAgICAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwYzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
RE4+uXR21aITVSzGh6O1mawGhId/dQb8vxRMDsxuxN89txJx9OjxUUAiKEngHUuH
qDTMBqLdElrRhjZkAzVvb3du6/KFUJheqwNTrZEjYx8WnM25sgVjOuH0aBsXBTWV
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

AND `gd_bundle_02.crt`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
56yDqg+2DzZduCLzrTia2cyvk0/ZM/iZx4mERdEr/VxqHD3VILs9RaRegAhJhldX
RQLIQTO7ErBBDpqWeCtWVYpoNz4iCxTIM5CufReYNnyicsbkqWletNw+vHX/bvZ8
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

then on your server do this

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https');

var ssl = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt', 'utf8'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('./ssl/bundle_01.crt', 'utf8'),
         fs.readFileSync('./ssl/bundle_02.crt', 'utf8')]
};

https.createServer(ssl, function(req, res) {
    //... your code here ...
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: I have received two files from Godaddy. One is smaller and it contains only one certificate. Another one is named gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt. I understand that I need to break it... but where is my key file?

Comment: you have to generate the CSR key file in your server, check GoDaddy help for this in here http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5276/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-tomcat-4-x5-x6-x

Comment: you can use this command too... `$openssl genrsa -des3 -out www.yourdomain-example.com.key 2048`

Comment: How to split the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt file? Copy and paste the certificate block in a new file and save it with the extension of crt is enough?

Comment: If you have renewed your certificate, you can use the previously generated key.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had a similar problem with Godaddy's SSL certificates on one of our node.js servers. In my case the problem was with one of our servers validating the SSL using PHP's curl functions.

It turns out I had to choose **SHA-1 signature** algorithm when submitting the CSR to Godaddy. I guess it is more compatible with older systems.

Comment: Related: Mozilla's [Phasing Out Certificates with SHA-1 based Signature Algorithms](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/), Google's [An update on SHA-1 certificates in Chrome](http://security.googleblog.com/2015/12/an-update-on-sha-1-certificates-in.html), Microsoft's [SHA-1 Deprecation Update](http://security.googleblog.com/2015/12/an-update-on-sha-1-certificates-in.html), etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Simpler**

Why be so specific just for GoDaddy's CA bundle when you can keep the same approach for different environments? I only need two files for dev env for example but production is using GoDaddy certs and has many so what to do?

For GoDaddy, I take their bundle and append it into a single file and name the extension as PEM as well as the key file which gives a pretty standard approach for all types of certs.

Then you end up just doing this for all environments:

```
server = https.createServer({           
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.sslKey),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCert),
},app).listen(config.sslPort);
```

In your GoDaddy cert.pem file you just place your certificate and your bundle files from 1 to x (top to bottom) and you're done like so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
site certificate goes here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CA 1 goes here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CA 2 goes here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CA X goes here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Not necessarily better but I prefer it. I didn't encounter on Express 3.x that I had to do the CA array route but I could be wrong for the specific version.