# Using GoDaddy's HTTPS certificates in nodejs: cert.crt and sf_bundle-g1-g2.crt

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I have found this related question:

[Running SSL node.js server with godaddy gd_bundle.crt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224064/running-ssl-node-js-server-with-godaddy-gd-bundle-crt)

which outlines the process of splitting the certificates, but uses three properties: certificate, ca, and key. I have only two files from my HTTPS registration with GoDaddy:

```
cert.crt (Not the name of the original but I'm fairly confident this is the certificate)
sf_bundle-g1-g2.crt (Is the actual name of the provided file)
```

Now the documents and file name seem to claim that sf bundle is a combination of two certificates, but mine looks like so:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFADCCA+igAwIBAgIBBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBjzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
EDAOBgNVBAgTB0FyaXpvbmExEzARBgNVBAcTClNjb3R0c2RhbGUxJTAjBgNVBAoT

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEoDCCA4igAwIBAgIDORSEMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGgxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MSUwIwYDVQQKExxTdGFyZmllbGQgVGVjaG5vbG9naWVzLCBJbmMuMTIwMAYDVQQL

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
3QUmNUqMZbhSa4Hs0py1NBCXnD7GL+2OQkIkLulzmiX5EfHyI2nL5ZRpoNLcsPxE
iawXqMzVN3cWxYC5DI9XAlWZhXtJ8C5boMJXU12i6KY3wwH6
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Again, I've combed the documentation and it seems I simply provide the location of all 3 of these in the options.ca array property in nodeJS' https module.

However it seems like I am missing a file. I have a cert, and 3 ca's, but no key. Is this an acceptable configuration? Or is some part of the sf_bundle supposed to be my key? It says -g1-g2 but contains 3 certificate sections.

I am entirely new to encryption, so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up simply being going back to godaddy and requesting the certificates in my desired format.

I attempted splitting it up and using the key we signed the certificates with, as suggested by mscdex. I could not get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is the private key you used to sign the CSR that you sent to GoDaddy.

Comment: Thanks, a systems engineer handled this for me, so I was unaware. If this is all I was missing and I get HTTPS implemented I will accept your answer.